# Cmake project works well. But intellisense does not work

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2017, intellisense, c99

[image: Intellisense does not work]

I am studying cmake project in visual studio 2017. It does not look like working. But Building and executing works well. Why does not intellisense work?

`project directory(CMakeLists.txt, CMakeSettings.json)`

```
main directory(main.c, CMakeLists.txt)
include directory(myprint.h)
printstatic directory(printstatic.c, CMakeLists.txt)
printshared directory(printshared.c, CMakeLists.txt)
```

"myprint.h"

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_test_static_library();
void print_test_shared_library();
```

"main.c"

```
#include "myprint.h"

int main()
{
    for (int ii = 0; ii < 3; ++ii) {
        printf("Hello CMake..................\n");
        print_test_static_library();
        print_test_shared_library();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

"CMakeLists.txt of main"

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

add_executable (main "main.c")
target_link_libraries(main printstatic printshared)
```

"printstatic.c"

```
#include "myprint.h"

void print_test_static_library()
{
    printf("Test Static Library..................\n");
}
```

"CMakeLists.txt of printstatic"

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

add_library (printstatic "printstatic.c")
```

"printshared.c"

```
#include "myprint.h"

void print_test_shared_library()
{
    printf("Test Shared Library..................\n");
}
```

"CMakeLists.txt of printshared"

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

add_library (printshared SHARED "printshared.c")
```

"CMakeLists.txt of project"

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

project ("CMakeProjectTest")

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
add_subdirectory ("printstatic")
add_subdirectory ("printshared")
add_subdirectory ("main")
```

"CMakeSettings.json"

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux-Debug",
            "generator": "Unix Makefiles",
            "remoteMachineName": "${defaultRemoteMachineName}",
            "configurationType": "Debug",
            "remoteCMakeListsRoot": "/home/mary/proj/src/${workspaceHash}/${name}",
            "cmakeExecutable": "/usr/local/bin/cmake",
            "buildRoot": "${env.USERPROFILE}\\CMakeBuilds\\${workspaceHash}\\build\\${name}",
            "installRoot": "${env.USERPROFILE}\\CMakeBuilds\\${workspaceHash}\\install\\${name}",
            "remoteBuildRoot": "/home/mary/proj/build/${workspaceHash}/build/${name}",
            "remoteInstallRoot": "/home/mary/proj/build/${workspaceHash}/install/${name}",
            "remoteCopySources": true,
            "remoteCopySourcesOutputVerbosity": "Normal",
            "remoteCopySourcesConcurrentCopies": "10",
            "remoteCopySourcesMethod": "sftp",
            "remoteCopySourcesExclusionList": [
                ".vs",
                ".git"
            ],
            "rsyncCommandArgs": "-t --delete --delete-excluded",
            "remoteCopyBuildOutput": false,
            "cmakeCommandArgs": "",
            "buildCommandArgs": "",
            "ctestCommandArgs": "",
            "inheritEnvironments": [
                "linux_x64"
            ]
        }
     ]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: @Max Vollmer Thank you. It always does. I think it is related to set 'c99'. If declaration of 'int ii' is positioned outside 'for', It works well. I don't know how to set intellisense.

Comment: Is the project in Visual Studio by any chance targeting ARM? Can you try changing that to x64 or x86?

Comment: I renamed *.c to *.cpp (ex: main.c -> main.cpp). Intellisense works well. Why not *.c?

Comment: Well, C++ is a different language, I don't see how that's relevant to your issue. Did you try changing the project target as I suggested?

Comment: Declaring `int ii` in the 'for' is only allowed in C99, but it seems only the Intellisense is not picking up the C99 setting. Others have seen and reported this [issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c94c606b-d454-4ac2-b3f1-141a30dede29/gcc-arm-intellisense-is-using-ansi-c-standard?forum=visualstudiogeneral), and it appears Microsoft may address it via a preprocessor overhaul.

Comment: @Max Vollmer Yes, I have tried x64, ARM, Linux and Ming. It works well in only x64.

Comment: What @squareskittles said. I had my answer typed up already, but wanted to wait for your response regarding the target settings, which confirms that this is the same bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in Intellisense when targeting ARM. [You are not the only one](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c94c606b-d454-4ac2-b3f1-141a30dede29/gcc-arm-intellisense-is-using-ansi-c-standard).

By switching the project target to x64 or x86, Intellisense should correctly parse the code as C99. If you need to target ARM, you just have to ignore those red lines for the time being.

Either way you might want to file a bug report to Microsoft.